# Best way to handle Sonar rule "Use Index Of Char"

Tags: java, sonarqube

I get a Sonar major violation on the following method:

```
private String getRequestId() {
    final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return uuid.substring(uuid.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, uuid.length());
}
```

Sonar advices me to use `String.indexOf(char)` when checking for the index of a single character since it executes faster than `String.indexOf(String)`.

I get that.

What I don't get is how to apply this advice on my code in an efficient way.

Comment: Don't get confused about the method `#indexOf` in this advice. The important part is the type of the passed parameter. Sonar suggests to use a `char` instead of a `String` like you currently do with `uuid.lastIndexOf("-")` (mind that `"-"` is a `String` literal). A way to change that code is in Ascalonians answer.

Comment: Please add tag for sonar. Is it SonarQube?

Comment: @Tom - Makes total sense when you put it that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use single quotes around the dash like so:  `uuid.lastIndexOf('-');`